# How to validate object with form validation [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I am trying to do validation something like this:

```
foreach (json_decode($this->request->get('depencies')) as $deps) {
   print_r($deps->id);
   $rules['depencies.' . $deps->id] = "exists:tasks,id,admin_id,$adminId|numeric";
}
```

But don't work. Any solution for this?

Comment: You should decide how you want to validate data and what should be result of such validation. In Laravel 5.2 you can to it much simpler using array validation - look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.2 (Array validation)

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.0... I need to validate every object inside `json_decode($this->request->get('depencies'))` by `id`